# Are there any HTML5 or Jquery plugins that can display videos like in this article?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make a web page like this article

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/19/arts/artsspecial/new-whitney-museum.html?_r=1

You can scroll down the text, and when a video takes up a portion of the screen it automatically rises to take up the entire screen and then auto plays. It also disables scrolling for a bit. If you scroll to the top and then back down it repeats this process.

Are there any plugins that have already implemented this or will I have to make it myself?

Comment: As an aside - I really don't like this effect (from a UX perspective). All of a sudden (without warning) the page interferes with my scrolling. But I suppose that's irrelevant to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need a plugin for that

you can do something like this, which first checks if the scrollTop (which is the distance to the top) is higher than what your video have to the top.

If it is higher, then we gonna play the video.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('video#yourVideoId').offset().top) {
       $('video#yourVideoId'').trigger('play');
    }
});
```